# Download Data from HPC to Zenodo Directly

Tags: github, data-storage, zenodo

I am ssh'd into an HPC system, and I have a bunch of old data on there I would like to store on Zenodo.  However, the only solution I have found so far is to create a Github repo, commit the data to said repo, then transfer the data from the Github repo to Zenodo.  I would really like to know if there is a way to do this directly from the HPC system to Zenodo, especially because I know Github has some limits on the data to be stored on its servers, much smaller than Zenodo (1G vs 50 G). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately the best answer I found was to download my data to my home machine and then upload it to Zenodo.  This was tedious and took days, so if there ever is an answer to this question at some point in the hopefully not-too-distant future, I would love to know about it, please post the answer here.  I am pretty certain I will have to do this again at some point.

Comment: There are two options one can use to solve this problem, but my answer was deleted after two years being posted on here so I don't remember all the details and have not needed to use Zenodo since that time, and I don't have time to think about this again after so many years.  "Found a way to do this after reaching out to the Zenodo team, but it would have been impossible to find otherwise.
    using curl: https://gist.github.com/slint/2263b2212743a68b2851b2cb7865675e
    using Python: https://gist.github.com/slint/92e4d38eb49dd177f46b02e1fe9761e1"